# Why is Jest async () causing a syntax error?

Tags: node.js, syntax-error, jestjs

I'm using Jest for a school project but whenever I make a test using async () it return a syntax error.
This is the 
[Syntax error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfI9B.png) and this the

```
test('POST /userGroups; should return 201 + userGroup obj', async () => {
    expect.assertions(2);
    let response = await request(app).post('/userGroups').set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + validId).send({user:dummyTeacher, userGroup:dummyUserGroup});
    expect(response.statusCode).toBe(201);
    expect(response.body).toBeDefined();
    dummyUserGroup.id = response.body.id;
    dummyUserGroup.creator = response.body.creator;
    validUGId = dummyUserGroup.id;
});
```

This is (a part of) the package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "db": "^1.1.1",
    "dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "google-auth-library": "^2.0.1",
    "mysql": "^2.16.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.3.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-google-oauth": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-http-bearer": "^1.0.1",
    "supertest": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^23.6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node -r dotenv/config ./server.js",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "collectCoverage": true
  }
```

I'm using node 6.15.1
What am I doing wrong? T_T

Comment: Hi! welcome to stack overflow, please include your code / errors in the post rather than screenshots.

Comment: Are you calling your test using the `jest` cli command?

Comment: No, I'm using npm test. I wanted to include the code into the post by the site wouldn't let me because it appeared that some code wasn't formatted as such.

Comment: Code must have 4 spaces in front of it so it formats correctly, use the `{}` button in the editor to shift it by 4 spaces

Comment: What's your `npm test` script contain?

Comment: I just call "npm test userGroups.test.js" which start the test suite

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Comment: I'm using the 6.15.1

Comment: Async/await requires node 7.5+

Comment: It was that. Thanks a lot :)